# MongoDB/Go Update multiple docs based on particular inner array value

Tags: mongodb, go

Assume I have following 'Games' collection document layout:[image]

Hello folks. I have multiple documents in collection with same layout where each document denotes some game session. What I want to do is when player gets more points is to update his score in each document and set 'Leader' and 'TotalScore' fields to values which are "Leader = Player with highest score in document", "TotalScore = Leader score minus 2nd place", when there is no advantage it is "None/0" respectively. I've managed to do it with the following code snippet:

```
        playerscore0 := BsonArrayValAt("Players", 0, "Score")
        playerscore1 := BsonArrayValAt("Players", 1, "Score")

        matchstage := bson.D{{Key: "$match", Value: bson.M{"_id": bson.M{"$in": User.Games}}}}
        unwindstage := bson.D{{Key: "$unwind", Value: "$Players"}}
        setscorestage := bson.D{{Key: "$set", Value: bson.M{"Players.Score": bson.M{"$cond": bson.M{
            "if":   bson.M{"$eq": bson.A{"$Players.Player", from}},
            "then": bson.M{"$sum": bson.A{"$Players.Score", score}},
            "else": "$Players.Score"}}}}}
        sortstage := bson.D{{Key: "$sort", Value: bson.M{"_id": 1, "Players.Score": -1}}}
        groupstage := bson.D{{Key: "$group", Value: bson.M{
            "_id":        "$_id",
            "Players":    bson.M{"$push": "$Players"},
            "Leader":     bson.M{"$first": "$Leader"},
            "TotalScore": bson.M{"$first": "$TotalScore"}}}}
        setleaderstage := bson.D{{Key: "$set", Value: bson.M{
            "Leader": bson.M{"$cond": bson.M{
                "if":   bson.M{"$gt": bson.A{playerscore0, playerscore1}},
                "then": BsonArrayValAt("Players", 0, "PlayerName"),
                "else": "None"}},
            "TotalScore": bson.M{"$cond": bson.M{
                "if":   bson.M{"$gt": bson.A{playerscore0, playerscore1}},
                "then": bson.M{"$subtract": bson.A{playerscore0, playerscore1}},
                "else": 0}}}}}
        mergestage := bson.D{{Key: "$merge", Value: bson.M{"into": "Games", "on": "_id", "whenMatched": "merge", "whenNotMatched": "discard"}}}

        pipeline := mongo.Pipeline{matchstage, unwindstage, setscorestage, sortstage, groupstage, setleaderstage, mergestage}
        if cur, err := GameStateC.Aggregate(context.TODO(), pipeline); cur != nil && err == nil {
} else {
some err handling
}

func BsonArrayValAt(arr string, idx uint, val string) bson.M {
    return bson.M{"$getField": bson.M{"field": val, "input": bson.M{"$arrayElemAt": bson.A{"$" + arr, idx}}}}
}
```

What bothers me is that there is much boilerplate for a task that seems pretty trivial. I assume I can't use indexed array access via dot notation as "Players.0.Score" in aggregation. Nor can I use ArrayFilters and $[] operator as those seems to be valid only in "update"-like commands. The main question is it better performance-wise to have one call to DB via aggregation or decouple this to separate "updateMany" where I can use dot notation and array filters and aggregation that will update "Leader/TotalScore". Or even update each document in some "foreach" manner. Thanks in advance for anyone who'll drop by to this question.